# Angular: ng-repeat. How do i target a specific item base on a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 2 sets of data that loads consecutively.

First data will defined the items to be repeated and trackby the id.

```
items:
    [{"id":21, "name":"john doe"},{"id":15, "name":"john doe"},{"id":13, "name":"john doe"}]
```

The next set of data i load will determine some status of the items, matched by the "id".

```
[{"idToMatch":15, "status":1},{"idToMatch":13, "status":1}]
```

I'm able to repeat the dom items by doing this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items trackby item.id">
{{item.name}}
</div>
```

What i would like to do is add a class to the items from the 2nd list matched by the "idToMatch" to the first set's "id".

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle to give a better idea of my data and what I'm having issues with.

[link]http://jsfiddle.net/6v3vo4nn/3/

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

In your controller:

```
//just for example
$scope.matches = [{"idToMatch":15, "status":1},{"idToMatch":13, "status":1}];

$scope.doesItemMatch = function(item) {
   for(var i in $scope.matches) {
      var match = $scope.matches[i];
      if(item.id === match.idToMatch)
        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

then in your html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items trackby item.id" ng-class="{yourClass: doesItemMatch(item)}">
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

[Edit]: here's a running example

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.items = [{
        "id": 21,
        "name": "john doe"
      }, {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "john doe"
      }, {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "john doe"
      }];
      $scope.matches = [{
        "idToMatch": 15,
        "status": 1
      }, {
        "idToMatch": 13,
        "status": 1
      }];

      $scope.doesItemMatch = function(item) {
        for (var i in $scope.matches) {
          var match = $scope.matches[i];
          if (item.id === match.idToMatch)
            return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```css
.test-class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'test-class': doesItemMatch(item)}">
      {{item.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around this and implement it. I think i might have over simplified my question thus my problem implementing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-class="{'yourClass': firstObject[item.idToMatch]}"
```

You can reference the item on the same DOM node you have ng-repeat

Comment: i don't think i can do this as my firstObject array, is not returned in order of the ids that correspond to the index. Also there will be missing IDs as certain items might have been "disabled".

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways. First to create a filter.

**Method 1**

Let's assume you have statuses like so

```
$scope.statuses = [{"idToMatch":15, "status":1},{"idToMatch":13, "status":1}]

$scope.myClass = function(item) {
    var out = 'class-';
    angular.forEach(statuses, function(v, k){
        if(v.idToMatch == input) {
            out += v.status;
            return false;
        }
    })
    return out;
}
```

And you can display status like so. Classes will be `class-1`, `class-2`, ...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items trackby item.id" ng-class="myClass(item)">
   {{item.id | status: statuses }}
</div>
```

Now create filter

```
app.filter('status', function(){
   return function(input, statuses) { 
       var out = '';
       angular.forEach(statuses, function(v, k){
           if(v.idToMatch == input) {
               out = v.status;
           }
       })
       return out;
   }
});
```

**Method 2**

Another way is to reformat your status direnetently.

```
$scope.statuses = [{15:1},{13:1}];
```

Now in template simply

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items trackby item.id" ng-class="'class-' + statuses[item.id]">
{{statuses[item.id]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. I think you got the answer to your question in the above answers. But you can take a look at this jsFiddle to get the most.

http://jsfiddle.net/Satbir/HB7LU/10396/

What I have done is that I created a function that will return true or false at a time based on if "id" exists in the "itemsToMatch" array of objects or not.

```
$scope.isItemExists = function (item) {

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemToMatch.length; i++) {
        if (item.id == $scope.itemToMatch[i].idToMatch) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then simple add the

```
ng-class="{color: isItemExists(item)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i might have over simplified my question thus my problem implementing the solution.

My first data set is in an array 2 levels deep. Group 1 -> Group 2 -> Data set.

```
 [{"groupid":1, 
     "anchors":[
       {"routes":[
          {"routeid":16}, 
          {"routeid":14}, 
          {"routeid":12} 
          ]  
       }]
   },
   {"groupid":2, 
     "anchors":[
       {"routes":[
          {"routeid":19}, 
          {"routeid":17}, 
          {"routeid":21} 
          ]  
       }]
   }
 ]
```

There is a main controller that loads the data above and the other data set for matching.
The groups, anchors n route arrays are repeated and nested within each other.
Only the routes items have their own controller which handle some interaction with the individual route items.

If i were to use the ng-class="myClass(item)", the function will be done in the item scope, but how can i access the list of items to match which sits in the parent scope or is that scope further away as the items is in another ng-repeat set?